# Getting errors after setting up apt-mirror

Tags: apt-mirror

I've installed apt-mirror following [this guide](http://www.matrix44.net/cms/notes/gnulinux/create-a-local-ubuntu-mirror) but I've made a couple of subtle changes as I've gone along and it has left me unsure how to proceed with the final step of scheduling this via `cron`.

I've decided I want the downloaded files in a folder structure `/var/mirror/...` as I have plenty of space here, and I changed the apt-mirror config as follows:

```
set base_path /var/mirror
set mirror_path $base_path/www
set var_path     $base_path/var
set skel_path    $base_path/skel
set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
```

If I run `sudo apt-mirror` It starts downloading (40Gb, not possible during the day) so wanted to let it run over night.

The file `/etc/cron.d/apt-mirror` contains:

```
30 01 * * *  apt-mirror  /usr/bin/apt-mirror > /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/cron.log
```

This is where I need help. If I run `sudo apt-mirror /usr/bin/apt-mirror > /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/cron.log` it exits with a configuration error:

```
apt-mirror: invalid line in config file (3: =pod ...) at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 297, <CONFIG> line 3.
```

I think this is because its trying to use `/usr/bin/apt-mirror` as a config file (cant get `apt-mirror --help` to work, and it gives me a similar error!) reading other documents and guides, it appears that `/usr/bin/apt-mirror` is to set the target location of the downloaded files, but this is not where I want them. I tried changing that to `/var/mirror/www` but it still gave me the configuration error.

So, can anyone either assist me with what the command within `cron` is actually doing so I can format appropriately, or can anyone confirm if I'm ok to just use `apt-mirror` within `cron` as it appears to work from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after some try and error I saw that I have 2 cron schedules for apt mirror.

1st which gave the error was in crontab of the user "apt-mirror" @1900h (time of mail) and a 2nd which did not gave any error in /etc/cron.d/apt-mirror @0400h.
After I disabled the 1900h job "crontab -u apt-mirror -e" the error was gone.

Hope this helps someone else.

Btw the syntax in the /etc/cron.d/apt-mirror file is little different than crontab file
the

```
/usr/bin/apt-mirror
```

is the apt-mirror script it self and the

```
apt-mirror
```

before the script is the username cron has to run the script as, an impersonationg thingy

> 30 01 * * *  apt-mirror  /usr/bin/apt-mirror > /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/cron.log
>
> > I think this is because its trying to use /usr/bin/apt-mirror as a config file